# LTC4060 NiMH charger 1A

Tags: batteries, charger, nimh

I'm designing a charger for 2 series NiMH batteries. After some research I came across the LTC4060. What I don't understand about this IC is how it is able to charge 1A over the small 0.25mm trace width of the IC pins. Below you can find two application from the datasheet. As far as I can understand figure 2 is never able to draw 2A of current. Maybe they switches the figure numbers. But even if that is the case, 0.25mm width is not enough for 1A of current. (According the KiCAD PCB calculator)

Wondering what your ideas are about these two applications. Is figure 3 an safer option?

Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily pass 1..2A through a .25mm track - you  don’t want to have that track too long as you will get excessive temperature rise. Fatten up the track as close as you can to the ic.